# Multiple screenshot using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

What are the steps to take multiple screenshots in selenium without updating the previous screenshot?

Comment: I have added an answer, Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

**Use this:**

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception { 
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
  driver.get("irctc.co.in/");  
    Date d =new Date();
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    // Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("E:\\selenium\\screenshot\\"+d.toString().replace(":", "_")+".png"));  
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to take screenshots as you have mentioned in Ques that multiple screenshots update the previous one each time rather than saving as new screenshot. I have added a way to store it differently using date Time as the name

Comment: i have done coding for single screenshot which updaates the previous saved screenshot with same same.

Comment: So If you change the name of the file before saving it will not update the previous one. Hope you get it.

Comment: this is the code for single screenshot.
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
 
//Open Browser
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();

//Enter the URL
driver.get("https://www.irctc.co.in/");

//FOR SIGNLE SCREENSHOT
File screenshotFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
Files.copy(screenshotFile, new File("E:\\selenium\\screenshot\\sample.png"));

Comment: that i know.. but i want to make automatically so that i dnt want to change name everytiem